# One Click Deployment Setup Requires Installation of .NET Framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, publishing, setup.exe

I'm trying to create an application that does not require admin rights to use.

When I publish the application there are 3 components shown:

1. A folder called "Application Files"
2. `setup.exe`
3. `MyApplicationName.application`

Running `MyApplicationName.application` executes my application as intended, adds an icon to the desktop and notifies the user when an update has been pushed out. :)

My users by default try to click on `setup.exe` and this requires them to get admin rights to install the application.

I can see two solutions and I'll accept either.

1. How do I get rid of the `setup.exe` file from being created on publish.
2. How do I get the `setup.exe` file not to require installation of the .NET framework or anything else that will need admin rights/privileges.

Comment: Did you try just deleting the "setup.exe" file after deployment?  I don't think it is required.

Comment: I'll be deploying my solution to many different locations. I can write a powershell script to go to each location and delete it but there has to be a better way than being reactive.

Comment: If your app runs on .Net 4.7.2, your clients need to have that installed - there is no way around it. You can migrate to .Net Core where you can have self-contained deployments without needing to pull the framework.

Comment: @trailmax what do you make of the fact that they can run it without installing anything if they use the other file. Is there a dependency I have included that I can remove to allow the setup.exe file to run without admin privileges? Also thank you for letting me know about self-contained deployments. I'll be looking into it when time permits.

Comment: If they can execute `myApp.exe` without installing the framework, then they already have the framework installed. That means your `setup.exe` does not check for the framework, just bluntly demands it to be installed.

Comment: Yes that is correct. How to I bluntly tell it not to install it. Note: Setup.exe also asks me to install it when I'm the one building the app and I know I have it installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of `Setup.exe` I had to unload my project in Visual Studio and edit the `.csproj` file.

The changes I've made are listed bellow.

Set BootstrapperEnabled to false

`<BootstrapperEnabled>false</BootstrapperEnabled>`

Deleted the section bellow

```
<BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2">
  <Visible>False</Visible>
  <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
  <Install>true</Install>
</BootstrapperPackage>
```